# How to make a function composer

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, function-composition

I am trying to make a function that rounds other functions for my university degree . For example I would like to call the `round_sqrt = round(sqrt)`
and when i call the `round_sqrt(5)` it has to shows me `2` instead of `2.23606797749979`. What I am trying is this:

```
def rounding(funct):
    return round(funct)
```

but this doesn't work.

EDIT: The function should have only one parameter. For example
the start of the function should be

```
def rounding(func):
```

so in this function the `funct` function needs to be rounded. 
so when I call `rounding(abs)(3.2)` it shows me `3`.

Comment: You are looking for function composition. Mathematically, `h = f ∘ g` is defined as `h(x) = f(g(x))`. While it would be nice if Python a composition operator were available in Python, practical concerns require you to define the composed function yourself.

Comment: playing with composition is one of the reasons I quickly fell in love with (then hated, then fell in love with, then hated, then...) Haskell.

Comment: Haskell is easy because everything fits into a theoretically sound mathematical framework. Haskell is hard because we are aren't use to conforming to said framework. :)

Comment: You can either leave the question to help other people or delete it, but please don't just remove all the content.

Comment: @AdamSmith Sounds like you were composing `hate . love . hate . love`

Comment: @AdamSmith You will love, hate J (http://www.jsoftware.com/) then.

Comment: @chepner i‘d say the composition function fits the mathematical definition of „operator“

Comment: @fpbhb Of course it does. That doesn't mean there will ever be a *Python* operator that creates a new functions. Let's say `f` returns a 2-tuple, with `def g(a, b=3)`. Now, should `(g ∘ f)(x)` be the same as `g(f(x))` or `g(*f(x))`? Or should there be separate operators for each? There are lots of reasonable ways to extend composition to Python's concept of a function. And what should metadata like name and docstring for the new function be set to? Should the metadata from the original functions be used in some way?

Comment: @chepner Now I see what you mean: you basically say that an operator (syntax-wise) simply wouldn't be expressive enough to cover composition for Python's function semantics, right?

Comment: More or less :) There is a whole list of combinations for which you might want something described as composition: `g(f(x))`, `g(*f(x))`, `g(**f(x))`, `h(f(x), **g(x))`, `h(*f(x), **g(x))` come to mind. (Things like `h(f(x), g(x))` could be handled with a separate operator or syntax, perhaps `h ∘ (f, g)`.) And even assuming you could convince enough people that any such proposal (or subset thereof) is worth adding to the language, what token would you actually choose? There is strong resistance to adding Unicode operators, and acceptable ASCII operators are nearly exhausted.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For your specific example, you can write

```
def round_sqrt(x):
    return round(sqrt(x))
```

[Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53194540/1126841) generalizes this; he defines a function that *creates* `round_sqrt` for you. If the function is already defined, you just pass it as an argument to `rounder`:

```
round_sqrt = rounder(sqrt)
```

Of course, you don't need to define `round_sqrt` if you don't want to. `rounder(sqrt)(3.2)` can be called directly, although it's far more efficient to safe the return value of `rounder` if you expect to use it multiple times, rather than redefining it each time.

Otherwise, the decorator syntax is just short for (using Alex's example)

```
def adder(x, y):
    return x + y

adder = rounder(adder)
```

---

As I said in my comment, this is an example of implementing composition. Mathematically, composition is simple, because mathematical functions always take a single argument and return a single argument. As such, the composition of two functions `f` and `g` could always be defined simply as

```
def compose(f, g):
    def h(x):   # The name doesn't matter
        return f(g(x))
    return h
```

Then

```
round_sqrt = compose(round, sqrt)
```

(Ignoring all sorts of practical concerns around the implementation, Python could in theory even provide a Unicode operator `∘` for functions: `round_sqrt = round ∘ sort`. Explaining *why* this won't happen is beyond the scope of this answer.)

In Python, though, functions are far more complicated. They can take multiple arguments, they can accept arbitrary numbers of arguments and arbitrary keyword arguments, and while each technically returns a single value, that value can be a tuple which is thought of as multiple values or a `dict`. As a result, there may be many ways you might expect to pass the return value of `g` to a function `f`, more than can easily be accommodated in a simple `compose` function.

Comment: Shouldn't `return f(g(z))` be `return f(g(x))`?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know where `z` came from.

Comment: Wouldn't it be cleaner to use a lambda inside `compose`?

Comment: I find `def` to be clearer when it's possible to use it.

Answer (score 27):

You should check out closures:

```
def rounder(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        return round(func(*args, **kwargs))
    return inner
```

Then you can decorate functions using the `@` character:

```
@rounder
def adder(x, y):
    return x + y

print(adder(1.1, 2.2))
```

outputs `3`

Supplementary:

1. You can use [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) in your closure so you don't lose information (e.g. docstring, function name) about the original function.
2. There are a bunch of resources for learning about closures (e.g. [1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-closures/), [2](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/closure)) and decorators (e.g. [1](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/), [2](https://www.thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/)) that you can find by Googling those terms.

Comment: Hey look, a decorator!

Comment: I cant understand anything. The answer should be more easier I think

Comment: @phpkubrick what? It's 3 lines of code and a function header? How much more simple would you like it? You mentioned you're in university -- you can understand this.

Comment: I cant understand the *args, **kwargs

Comment: @phpkubrick I guess that's the next bit of research you should do then, because they're used *all over the place* in Python and are incredibly useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters

Comment: So for example If I copy paste this on my idle will work? Because I thought that those was some parameters that I have to change

Comment: @Alex Making the fully general `rounder` function is really more complicated than needed to answer the question. You could start with `rounder` assuming `func` is a single argument function.

Comment: Could you also write it as returning a lambda function, i.e. `return (lambda *args, **kwargs: round(func(*args, **kwargs)))` ?

Comment: @DanielSchepler You could, but there's little reason to do so. Usually, using `def` where possible makes code easier to read.

Answer (score 5):

Function composition isn't supported natively in Python. You can use a decorator as per [@Alex's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53194540/9209546). You can define a new function explicitly as per [@chepner's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53194655/9209546).

Or you can use a 3rd party library. For example, via [`toolz.compose`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.functoolz.compose):

```
from toolz import compose

def adder(x, y):
    return x + y

round_adder = compose(round, adder)

round_adder(1.1, 2.2)  # 3
```